# php if in category not detected

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using advanced custom fields with wordpress.

I am trying to make it that if a subfield has a category of 8 it displays its repeater fields. If not it doesn't show the other posts.

However this doesn't seem to work and display the content:

```
<?php while(has_sub_field('team_profile')): ?>
        <?php $cat = 8;
          if (in_category($cat)) {
        ?>
            <li class="col-lg-3 teamProfile">
                <h2><?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?></h2>
                <p class="jobTitle"><?php the_sub_field('category'); ?></p>
            </li>
        <? } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `this doesn't seem to work and display the content`? What happens when you are in category 8 and what happens when you aren't?

Comment: It doesn't detect anything so nothing shows up, however there is content in category 8.

Comment: If you remove the `while` statement around the `if` statement will it work?

Comment: If you view the source of the page, is the `li` or `p` tags showing up at all?

Comment: No you dont see them. It ignores all the content in the li.

Comment: That should be working. Are you 100% sure you are on the category page for that id?

Comment: yes there is a category id, i could try using the name/slug instead of the number? But im not too sure how to do this.